# how i can control the properties/fields that can be retrieved from SharePoint inside my PnP core sdk

Tags: development, pnp

I have this pnp core sdk code:-

```
var myList = await context.Web.Lists.GetByTitleAsync("Work Orders", p => p.Title,
                                                      p => p.Fields.QueryProperties(p => p.InternalName,
                                                                                    p => p.FieldTypeKind,
                                                                                    p => p.TypeAsString,
                                                                                    p => p.Title));
 int i = 0;
 var t = "";
 // Do a paged retrieval of the list items
 await foreach (var listItem in myList.Items)
 {
     // Do something with the list item
     t= listItem["Created"].ToString();
     i++;
 }
```

now i am not loading the Created property, but how i were able to reference it inside my forrach loop? seems my code is loading all the properties, so how i can control which properties i want to get from sharepoint, so i can improve the response time and network utilization?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `QueryProperties` method when retrieving the items as well, here is the corrected code snippet:

```
var myList = await context.Web.Lists.GetByTitleAsync("Work Orders", p => p.Title,
                                                      p => p.Fields.QueryProperties(p => p.InternalName,
                                                                                    p => p.FieldTypeKind,
                                                                                    p => p.TypeAsString,
                                                                                    p => p.Title));

// Specify the fields to load for the items
await myList.LoadItemsAsync(p => p.QueryProperties(p => p["Created"], p => p["Title"]));

int i = 0;
var t = "";
// Do a paged retrieval of the list items
await foreach (var listItem in myList.Items)
{
    // Do something with the list item
    t= listItem["Created"].ToString();
    i++;
}
```